# Hexo site generator - use templates for PHP pages

Tags: javascript, generator, ejs, hexo

I use [Hexo](https://hexo.io/) to generate a Website. The .ejs files are producing .html files. Is it possible to produce out also .php or .pad files ? I have to render few .php pages using the same templating mechaninsm, or pad.xml using some variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out?

```
# _config.yml
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title.php # Suffix '.php'
```